# Problem with extruding along normals

Tags: normals, extrude

When I try to extrude along normals, it goes up and down instead of outwards. Any help? I'm still relatively new.

Like this I extruded faces along normals ...

[image]

Comment: we need more information or even better the file to look at.
could be flipped normals ?

Comment: hello, also have you applied the scale in Object mode?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_Jnne7RSpVGL8Ra6o2XOHMJtXKiCB71/view?usp=share_link heres the file

Answer (score 0):

If you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> you get a menu for extrude options. One of then is Extrude Faces Along Normals:

[image]

You could just extrude normally and finish the operation and then use Shrink/Flatten - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Thats is what i did it didnt work

Comment: OK, so what have you tried to solve it? Does this happen to one object only? Did you apply scale like suggested in the comments? You should check if the object has something weird going on with its modifiers as well. You should share the file if you wish to get a better answer. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the cylinder im trying to extrude the faces of https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TQyJrKicRscqXRXC4NVz2P2tc07Jk_0R/view?usp=share_link

Comment: OK, well it's a mesh exported to FBX format, not a .blend file...

Comment: Oh my bad heres a blend file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_Jnne7RSpVGL8Ra6o2XOHMJtXKiCB71/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Seems to me you have your answer in the comments already.

Comment: what do you mean